# Customize the Display of Quick Launch

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, quick-launch

I need a Quick Launch with 4 menu levels, and I want to collapse/expand menu. I edit master page in SharePoint Designer 2010, I change `StaticDisplayLevels` attribute and the `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` attribute to 4 in `V4QuickLaunchMenu` but it cannot show 3rd and 4th menu level.

The 3rd menu level is not a folder in Library? How I manage the 3rd & 4th menu level?

I refer to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994(v=office.14).aspx

Here is my code in master page:

```
 <SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical"
StaticDisplayLevels="4" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" 
SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
```

Comment: Replace `ASPMenu` with `TreeView` as explained in the same article. The use the `Site Setting` -> `Navigation` to set the items

Comment: Hi @AmalHashim, if I replace `AspMenu` with `TreeView`, I cannot manage `AspMenu` in `Navigation`, I think `Navigation` is for `AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"`

Comment: And there is no 3rd & 4th level in `Navigation` :(